# Apple Script "display notification" works within Script Editor, not from launchd

Tags: macos, applescript, plist, launchd

I started using launchd and encounter a peculiar issue. When I send a "display notification" it works fine from within Script Editor but not from launchd. The "say" command actually does work from launchd. For testing I also tried the "display dialog" command, which also doesnt work from launchd. A final say command after this is also not audible.

I checked the manual pages for Launchctl but found nothing related to this issue.

I also tried to place the plist in the System Library/LaunchAgents instead of the ~/Library/LaunchAgents but the behaviour was identical.

Here is the script code, containing remarks what works where and when:

```
say "This is before the display notification"
## the say command is audible both from within
## the script editor AND from launchd

display notification "Less than 20% Battery Remaining, plug in soon." with title "Batterij opladen" sound name "Basso"
## the display notification command is working
## fine within Script Editor, but not from launchd

say "This is after the display notification"
## the say command is audible both from 
## within the script editor AND from launchd

set theResponse to display dialog "What's your name?" default answer "" with icon note buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button "Continue"
--> {button returned:"Continue", text returned:"Jen"}
display dialog "Hello, " & (text returned of theResponse) & "."
## the display dialog command is working 
## fine within Script Editor, but not from launchd

say "This is after the display dialog"
## this say command is audible from within the 
## script editor but NOT from launchd
## so this part is not executed
```

My implementation: (1) sudo su root for root privileges
(2) I copy the script to the /etc folder
(3) I create the plist in Apple TextEdit.app
(4) I copy the plist to the ~/Library/LaunchAgents folder
(5) I check the plist using plutil: no errors
(6) I set the plist attributes using sudo chown root TestSpk.plist
(7) Then I run the plist using Launchctl load TestSpk.plist
(8) The launchctl list | grep TestSpk returns zero so the plist should be working fine

Here is the plist code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <false/>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>TestSpk</string>
  <key>LowPriorityIO</key>
  <true/>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/bin/osascript</string>
    <string>/etc/TestSpk.scpt</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>ServiceDescription</key>
  <string>TestSpk</string>
  <key>StartInterval</key>
  <integer>10</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

In Notification Center, the Scripteditor is set to allow notifications.

What am I missing?

Thanks, Pete

Comment: I may be completely wrong on this, but I think the issue is that `launchd` doesn't know whose display/session to display on - remember there could be many users logged in at any time. But there's only one default audio device so it does know where to send sound when you use `say`. I'm thinking it's similar to trying to use X11 programs from `cron` jobs.

Comment: Good thinking, thanks. I figured the system would know as the plist is placed within the user lib. And the original script contains the same syntax: https://jmmoloney.com/blog/2019/02/06/batteryscript.

Comment: For testing purposes only while logged into an **Admin** account with an active session, no screen saver and display awake, I created a _shell script_ using a `#!/usr/bin/osascript` _shebang_ and two lines of **AppleScript** _code_, `display notification "Foobar"` and `say "foobar"`, made it executable, moved it to `/usr/local/bin/` setting permissions to `0775`.  I then added a `com.me.foobar.plist` _file_ to `~/Library/LaunchAgents` setting it to run in a few minutes. When the set time came, a notification was displayed and "foobar" was spoken. So, under the conditions stated it does work.

Comment: That said, other conditions _may_ cause a different result. Using a **Standard** account, screen saver running, display sleeping, lock screen showing, user logged out, permissions not set properly, notebook in clamshell mode without an external display attached, etc. You'll just have to do some testing to see which conditions keeps it from working as described in my first comment.

Comment: Correction on the permissions, I set to to `0755` not `0775`.

Comment: @user3439894 if you could post your script and plist I could give them a go on my machine. Alternatively, what happens when you run my OP script and plist?

Comment: Very curious: the script that does run on my Catalina machine (though it only executes the "say" command, not the "display notification") won't even run at all on my M1 macbook air. I follow the exact same steps, but "Launchctl list" returns 1 instead of 0. May be due to stricter security regime.

Comment: RE: " if you could post your script and plist I could give them a go on my machine" --  You'll obviously will need to adjust the _time_ in the **.plist** for when it executes. https://paste.ee/p/o9HxJ

Comment: Thanks. Can't make it work though. So when I'm in terminal, do I sudo as root to launchctl load com.me.foobar.plist? In your screen shot I noticed your plist is owned by "me" so that makes me think you run the script as user, not root. I'm clearly missing a lot of knowlegde and experience here. Can't blame you if you give up on this one. Too much time effort for me to learn in depth. I just spent two full days to get where I am, just trying to make them count.

Comment: To get an idea of how I did this, have a look at my answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/413619/sound-often-randomly-disappears-from-menu-bar/413629?r=SearchResults&s=2|0.0000#413629) but substitute the information in the previous link as applicable. Let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure what has been going on, but after a reboot all display notifications that I previously had in my own script just work. All that I need to figure out is why the same script won't work in Big Sur on my M1 MBA.

Comment: @user3439894 I followed your example and it also runs perfectly fine on my 2013 MBP. As the issue in this topic had been solved, I moved the Big Sur issue to a [new topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67659856/simple-apple-script-works-under-catalina-doesnt-work-under-big-sur-on-m1-mba), with a new source code.