# Simple Apple Script works under Catalina, doesn't work under Big Sur on M1 MBA

Tags: macos, applescript

I developed a script on my 2013 MBP (works fine), aiming to run it later on a series of M1 MBA's (doesn't work at all on those). So I created a simple test script following [this method](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/413619/sound-often-randomly-disappears-from-menu-bar/413629#413629). The test script runs perfectly fine on the 2013 MBP but also doesn't show any sign of life on the M1.

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

set mySSID to do shell script "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I | awk '/ SSID/ {print substr($0, index($0, $2))}'"
display notification mySSID
display alert mySSID
```

made executable by chmod +x, then moved to /usr/local/bin/
On the M1 I had to create the bin folder as there wasn't any under /usr/local/

Then created a plist in the ~/Library/LaunchAgents folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.my.checkssid</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/checkSSID</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>10</integer></dict>
</plist>
```

This method was confirmed to work by the contributor.

I also restarted the M1 but that also doesn't work.
When I put the plist in ~/Library/LaunchAgents and restart the machine, the plist is active when I grep a list and returns "-  0   com.my.checkssid".

plutil returns 0 (no errors)

The script runs fine on the M1 from the script editor

when I put the plist in ~/Library/LaunchAgents and reboot, the plist is active.
I can unload it by using "launchctl unload <...>"

Is there another way to see if the script is called at all?

Any clues?

Thanks, Pete

Comment: I do not have access to an **M1** so I'm not sure I can be of help in that respect. I do what to mention that having to create the `bin` _directory_ is not at all unusual on a clean install of **macOS** and or if there has been no reason to have it previously. The irony is that **Apple** includes `/usr/local/bin` in the default `PATH` even though it may not exist. BTW The **Launch Agent** shown in your OP works in **macOS Big Sur** on an **Intel** based **Mac**.

Comment: BTW In **Terminal**, e.g., `launchctl list | grep com.my.checkssid` should return  a `PID` and `0` if it executed successfully, e.g., `2582 0 com.my.checkssid`

Comment: Yes Library/LaunchAgents, I was typing lazily, sorry. Edited and fixed. Terminal cd command doesn't mind though.

Comment: Thank you for testing my script under Big Sur (appreciate it!), must be the M1 or smth with the unit or settings. Can anyone who owns an M1 confirm?

Comment: BTW I studied the launchctl man pages and the hyphen in "-   0   com.my.checkssid" means it's not running, so the zero probably doesn't mean much yet as it's the result of the last run. I have 4 identical M1 units at my disposal. Will try a second unit.

Comment: @Peter376: in "- 0 com.my.checkssid", the initial dash '-' means the process is not *currently* running (has no PID), but the zero '0' means the process ran at least once prior (in this session) with no error.

Comment: Does running `checkSSID` in **Terminal** work?

Comment: Thank you @TedWrigley.  That is good to know.

Comment: @user3439894 I ran checkSSID in Terminal, did not work. *Error: zsh: /usr/local/bin/checkSSID: bad interpreter: /usr/bin/osascript^M^Mset mySSID to do shell script "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Res: exec format error.* Then I looked for /usr/bin/osascript, it's not there. I ran a more simplified script (replaced Apple80211.framwork line by 'set mySSID to "string"'. Got the same error. So it would seem that the osascript interpreter is missing.

Comment: RE: "^M^M" --  There is the problem! Where/how did you create the `checkSSID` _file_, under **Windows**?  Copy and paste the _code_ from the OP under **macOS** into a new document of the name `checkSSID` and replace the original.

Comment: @user3439894 First, osascript is there, not sure how I could have missed that, sorry. Absolutely no Windows. I actually followed [your steps](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/413619/sound-often-randomly-disappears-from-menu-bar/413629#413629) meticulously. Every new script I create using touch - open - chmod +x - paste code - save - sudo mv to /usr/local/bin/.

Comment: No offenses, but you couldn't had followed it explicitly as you have `CR` in the file.  If in **Terminal** if you run `file /path/to/checkSSID` on the original `checkSSID` it will return `ASCII text, with CR line terminators` and there are no CR line terminators in what I wrote in the linked answer.

Comment: Well I didn't use your script, I wrote my own in Script Editor checked if it is ok, then copied from SE and pasted it in your workflow after touch - open - chmod +x. It's the exact same workflow as I used under Catalina and there it will run without issue.

Comment: Bottom line is your script is corrupted and is not from my instructions! Fix your script and you'll probably fix your issue!

Comment: Yes you are right, and I can't thank you enough for staying with me this far. I merely report back what I'm doing and it paid off as you noticed something important. I will try to find a way to fix it. Apparently I used a CR somewhere in the process without being aware of it. All I used were MacOS native TextEdit and Scritp Editor apps, not Windows. I did apply "make plain text" at some point. I'll dive into this further. Really thank you for your replies.

Comment: Okay after some testing I found that when I first create, compile and test a script using the M1 Big Sur native Script Editor app, it will in fact contain the ^M / CR returns. If I then copy that script from the Script Editor and paste it into the text file created by 'touch checkSSID' etc. the executable will fail with the error message above containing the ^M characters. On my Intel machine this isn't the case.

Comment: @user3439894 When I create a blank text file using your 'touch' command and type the same script syntax from zip in that TextEdit.app window, then save and move it to /usr/local/bin/ it does in fact show the display notification now for the first time. Like I said I did all this in exactly the same way on my Intel/Catalina MBP and had no such issues. So I suppose to solve this issue I need to change the editor I am using to compose the script. This apparently is a change on the M1 macs. I confirmed the above on a second M1 MBAir. May I ask what editor you use to compose your scripting? Cheers.

Comment: As I previously mentioned I do not have access to an **M1** and it's really sad to here that **Apple** has screwed up **Script Editor** on the **M1**, and just another reason while I'll never own an **M1**! On my **Intel** based **Mac**, I use several different apps when writing _code_ depending on what language.  **Script Editor**, **Sublime Text**, **BBEdit** and **TextEdit** in **Plain Text** mode. I used all of these with **AppleScript** but mostly **Script Editor**, **Sublime Text** for **AppleScript**. I think I had to add an Extension for **AppleScript** in **Sublime Text**.

Comment: **Script Debugger** is also good with **AppleScript**.

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks a lot I checked out Sublime Text and it looks nice. I did find a workaround via TextEdit. Thanks to your excellent work I now know what to look for (avoid the CR). Still can't thank you enough, you saved my project!

Comment: @user3439894 So the workaround is this: On M1 units: use native Script editor to compose, compile, test, adjust. Then use the menu "Archive->Export" command and select 'Structure: Text' and 'end of line: macOS / Unix (LF)'. The exported file is of type text with extension .applescript. Open that file with TextEdit. Next, start your workflow (touch - open - chmod) and copy the syntax from the new text file and paste it in. From there on it's your workflow (sudo mv -v, sudo -k) and create the plist (I used the one above in my OP). I just tried to load the plist and the test script went okay.

Comment: @user3439894 so from here I will now go back to my original script and see if all the code in that one will in fact work on the M1. Additional components of that script are the actual SSID check as in my OP and some sound level adjustments. Can't wait to finish the job now. Thanks again for your analysis.

Comment: @user3439894 six weeks down the road and all scripts I throw at the M1 work flawlessly. The workaround isn't that much of a hassle. I am rigidly following the steps you described every time and they just work every time. I'm developing the script further and further, am now on v.1.8.1 for script one and v1.3.3 for script 2. Feeling like a real software developer...  Really the M1 is a pleasant and powerful machine, without the mountain of issues that people were afraid of when it was announced. I say you're missing out if you let this stop you. Not affiliated with Apple, just honest advice.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be interested to know whether this works, having not yet upgraded to Big Sur nor the M1:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
use framework "CoreWLAN"
use scripting additions

get the ssid() of the sharedWiFiClient()'s interface() ¬
    of the current application's CWWiFiClient as text

display alert result
```

Comment: The ASObjC works fine on Big Sur, but `display notification` seems to be FUBAR.

Comment: That’s a shame, @TedWrigley.  At least, from what I’ve seen, the alert dialog boxes look pretty.

Comment: `display alert` and `display dialog` still work fine; it's just `display notification` (giving a sidebar notification) that's wonky. I even know why: just after Apple updated Standard Additions with the display notification command, they changed the ObjC framework that displays notifications, and the old system stopped working. If you want to write your own ASObjC code using the new framework (User Notifications, instead of the deprecated Notification Center), you could probably mock it up. @CJK